# Minimal Jquery TE textarea editor

Tags: jquery, text, editor

Can anyone advise where I might find a simple 'bare-bones' example of a working jQuery TE text editor.

I'm new to jquery, been to 'demo' sites and found it impossible to isolate 'text editor scripting' from the advertising/site code on the various on the demo pages.

If anyone can point me too a clear example of the minimal
code required (library dependencies, related head js, and a target text-area control) I will be most grateful. Thank you for in advance. Ken Ashton.

Comment: Are you asking for examples of web text editors? Or how to code one yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are looking for the actual Jquery TE Plugin, and not just 'a plugin like TE'...the best resource is their own [website](http://jqueryte.com/).

They have a demo page set up that has two different stylings of the plugin that you can mess with. To use the plugin, all you need is the plugin code, and the latest version of jquery. To use it at the barest level, here is some basic code.

HTML

```
<textarea id="someTextArea"></textarea>
```

JS

```
$("#someTextArea").jqte();
```

I'd set it up in a fiddle for you to mess with, but jqueryte doesn't have a web link, only downloads. Other than that, look at the Documentation page of jqueryte's site for further details on how you can customize the editor

Comment: If I use your suggested code -

Comment: Can you tell me what I am missing, could not get it working.        <html>
<head>
<title>Jquery TE test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryte.com/css/jquery-te.css" charset="utf-8" >

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#someTextArea").jqte();
</script>

</head>

<body>
<textarea id="someTextArea"></textarea>
</body>
</html>

Comment: You are referencing the core of jquery, and the CSS (style sheet) of jquery TE. You also need to download and reference the .js file for jquery TE